# LNK2019 and LNK1120 errors when compiling extension for python 2.7 on amd 64 windows 7

Tags: python, visual-c++

I'm trying to build a Python extension on an AMD 64-bit Windows 7 machine with Python 2.7 using "Visual C++ for Python". I was able to build without problems using GCC on a Mac.

I'm running this from the "Visual C++ 2006 64-bit Command Prompt".

Deep in compile, I get the following error:

```
Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\_c_louvain.lib and obje
ct build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\_c_louvain.exp


igraph.lib(math.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__dclass r
eferenced in function igraph_finite
build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\louvain\_c_louvain.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolv
ed externals
error: command '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Py
thon\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe"' failed with exit status 1120
```

The `math.obj` file is in the same place as the `igraph.lib`, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Any suggestions for trouble shooting for someone with very limited Visual C++ knowledge.

Comment: were you able to resolve the linker errors?